# Variable is used before it has been assigned a value... Can't assign a value though

Tags: vb.net

This is Visual Basic 2012.

```
Dim webber As Net.WebClient
htmlsource = webber.DownloadString("some site here")
```

I just cannot figure out why it throws "Variable is used before it has been assigned a value" error.
I'm trying to download HTML source in UTF8, so I'm trying to put

```
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
```

too. How should I do this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim webber As Net.WebClient
```

This just declares the variable, but doesn't instantiate it.

```
Dim webber As New Net.WebClient()
```

This will declare and instantiate it in one step.